# still same error, module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'

Tags: tensorflow

Could you please help me with tensorflow? I have been very frustrated with tensorflow for many months. I know they don't work well with python 3.7. Now I am using python 3.6 with tensorflow 2.0.

What the heck this tensorflow? It is so frustrated to use tensorflow.

Here is my code:

```
import keras
import keras.backend as K
from keras.layers.core import Activation
from keras.models import Sequential,load_model
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM
```

The error of AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph' is for next line:

```
model = Sequential()
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I downgraded tensorflow from 2.0 to 1.8. then it runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing libraries like that:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM
```